# Why the time period of pendulum with infinite length is $84.6$ minutes?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, time, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

In a book I was reading about SHM it stated:

If the length of a simple pendulum is increased to such an extent that $\ell\to\infty$, then its time period is given by,

$$T=2\pi\sqrt\frac{R}{g}\approx84.6\text{ min}$$

Now I have many confusions like:

1. Doesn't the gravity change with such a large length and amplitude?
2. How can an infinitely long pendulum have a confined time period?
3. Some parts near the end may have a velocity greater than light.

Comment: An infinitely long object _cannot_ rigidly rotate at all, because then some of its parts would be moving faster than the speed of light.

Comment: We'll need more information to answer. What book and what page?

Comment: This period looks like the one of an object constrained to a straight line that passes through Earth. But that's a different kind of pendulum than what we normally call a simple pendulum.

Comment: I've exactly written what there is in the book.

Comment: What you have written is false. Simple as that. The period of a simple pendulum is proportional to the square root of its length. And that's ignoring relativistic effects (as well as the non-homogeneity of Earth's gravitational field, which kicks in much sooner), which provide a lower bound of $T = \Omega(l * \phi_{max})$.

Comment: you might think you've given all the relevant information, but just humor the two @john s and give us the page and title of book.

Comment: You may not have that book it's just a revision module.

Comment: What are the values of R and g? Or, what do they stand for?

Comment: @JohnDvorak I know it's wrong but that's what given that's why I've posted the question to get an answer.

Comment: @Dlamini $R$ is the radius of earth and $g$ is the gravity due to earth.

Comment: FWIW, that formula for T gives the rotation period of a sphere of radius R that has centripetal acceleration g. IOW, if Earth were spinning that fast you'd be weightless at the equator. (Of course, that wouldn't work in practice because the Earth isn't sufficiently rigid).

Comment: The OP’s statement is totally correct, but, uh, as usual for low-quality textbooks, it is stated extremely unclearly. This question shouldn’t be closed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\def\PD#1#2{{\partial#1 \over \partial#2}}$
I would suggest a different approach. If $l$ is very large the circumference of radius $l$ becomes a straight line, tangent to a circumference centred in Earth's centre C and radius $R$. If $x$ is bob's displacement along this line, bob's distance from C is $D=\sqrt{R^2+x^2}$ and gravitational potential energy is
$$V(x) = -{G\,M\,m \over D}.$$

The component of gravitational force along bob's trajectory is
$$F_x = -\PD Vx = -{G\,M\,m \over R^3}\,x = 
-{m\,g \over R}\,x$$
and the equation of the motion is
$$\ddot x = -{g \over R}\,x.$$
Then
$$\omega = \sqrt{g \over R} \qquad 
T = 2\,\pi\,\sqrt{R \over g}.$$

Comment: This seems to work, Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I have also studied this relation. May be things get clearer in my explanation:
For a general pendulum, it is obvious that if the l is substituted to a large value the time period corresponding also increases. For a pendulum of very large length(comparable to radius of earth), we have to make a change in derivation. An assumption which is valid only for small lengths. That is:
For small pendulums, on small angular displacement, the corresponding linear displacement is very small. The force of gravity (causing restoring torque) can be assumed to be vertically downwards. But for a hypothetical large pendulum, this is no more true. Even for a small angular displacement the corresponding linear distance on the ground becomes too large(if $\theta$ is the angular displacement the corresponding linear displacement is $L\theta$ where L is length of string). The force of gravity acts along line joining the Bob and centre of earth, and it is no more vertically downwards. (The angle moved by Bob with respect to centre of earth is no more negligible. It is given by $R_e \beta= L\theta. R_e$ is radius of earth  ) So the problem is that the torque due to gravity is no more given by the same expression. [image]
You can see the picture for clarification. The infinite is a hypothetical case by substituting $L=\infty$ .

Gravity as you said , is taken to be constant

Comment: So because of the small amplitude gravity is taken to be constant?

Comment: The L is too large then height difference will be there, but for large values of L especially tending to infinity, the difference is not taken into account. Maybe for simplicity also changes in gravity are neglected