# Time period of a simple pendulum at the centre of earth

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, harmonic-oscillator, thought-experiment

> So I thought of this hypothetical experiment and wondered whether it
> be possible for it to even happen at center of earth even though
> gravity is zero.

**So considering a pendulum with length much much less than the radius of earth and center at earth center's can you find the time period of the pendulum (or is it even defined) ?**

Comment: It boils down to finding potential

Comment: can you elaborate

Comment: Just to be clear on the scenario - we have an empty spherical pocket at the center of the earth, with the pendulum's pivot fixed at the center point. The pendulum hangs "up" from the center, and there's no gravity acting on the pendulum because there is no mass "below" it. Correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite an interesting question: let's consider the planet to be a solid sphere of constant density, and of some total mass $M$ and radius $R$. It's an exercise in undergraduate physics (using [Gauss's law for Gravitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law_for_gravity), for example) to show that the force exerted on a small mass $m$ at some distance $r$ from the origin is just: $$\mathbf{F} = - \frac{GM m r }{R^3} \hat{\mathbf{r}}.$$

You'll notice that the force is independent of the angles $\theta$ and $\varphi$, because of the symmetry of the problem. In other words, all that matters is how far away you are from the centre, your orientation is unimportant.

More interesting is the fact that the force is directly proportional to the distance from the centre, and in the opposite direction! If you wrote out the differential equation for this system, it would just be: $$\mathbf{a} = -\frac{GM}{R^3} r \,\,\hat{\mathbf{r}}.$$

This is just the differential equation for harmonic motion about the origin (i.e. the centre of the Earth)! By comparing it to the standard harmonic motion differential equation, you should be able to see that the angular frequency of oscillations $\omega$ is given by $$\omega = \sqrt{\frac{GM}{R^3}},$$ and so the time period is just $$T = \frac{2\pi}{\omega} = 2 \pi \sqrt{\frac{R^3}{GM}}.$$

For the Earth, this translates to a time period of $$T = 84.6 \text{ min}.$$

Curiously, this is also the [time period of an infinite pendulum](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/470460/157014), admittedly for slightly different -- though related -- reasons.

What is particularly curious about the problem is the following: as you know, on the surface of the Earth, the Pendulum only approximates harmonic motion in the small-angle approximation. If the angle is too large, the force is no longer proportional to displacement. Interestingly, however, *inside* a solid sphere of constant density, the pendulum is *truly* harmonic! Which means you could move it by quite a large angle, and it would still take exactly $84.6 \text{ min}$ to oscillate!

It should also be clear that this time marks an *upper bound* on the amount of time it would take to complete a round-trip between any two points on the planet if you dug a tunnel between them and "fell" through it!

Comment: well written mate! It makes sense to me and nice correlation too. Hope so I understood it well!

Comment: Another fun fact:  if the Earth didn't have an atmosphere, and a satellite could orbit right above the surface of the Earth, it would have this orbital period.

Comment: I'm confused - according to the Shell Theorem, there's no gravitational force whatsoever at the center of the earth. There's no mass "below" a pendulum in an empty pocket at the center of the earth, so it isn't affected by gravity at all. I don't see why you should start with any formula related to gravity when the pendulum is in a zero-G environment.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie Hi, what you say is true if there is a concentric spherical chunk taken out of the Earth within which the pendulum is placed. It is a valid point, and the other answer to this question addresses this. I, on the other hand, assume there to be a thin channel (or tunnel) cut out within which the "pendulum" oscillates. In this case, of course, the pendulum is no longer in a zero-G environment.

Comment: @Philip I see. Perhaps worth noting that the 84.6 minutes is an *upper bound* on the period - this is effectively a pendulum bob that's in orbit around the core, held at a particular radius by gravity alone, so it's a pendulum that doesn't actually need any string at all. But you could make it orbit faster by imparting additional velocity to the bob and putting tension in the string.

Comment: I have actually mentioned that when I speak of the tunnel. Are you sure that it's an upper bound for the oscillation time, though? I don't see why: from the equations of motion, this is purely harmonic motion, meaning that the oscillation frequency shouldn't depend on amplitude (so long as you're in the sphere). If you imparted additional velocity, I believe you will just be changing the shape of the orbit, not the overall time it would take.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on a detail that you have omitted: is the region of the Earth "within" the pendulum bob filled with mass, with a small planar slit cut to allow the pendulum to move friction-free, or is the pendulum in an empty pocket?

The answer for the first case has already been posted. The gravitational force on the bob acts towards the Earth's center with magnitude proportional to the distance from the center. The result is a nice harmonic motion with a period of roughly 84 minutes.

In the second case, though, no force acts on the bob. It is inside a uniform shell of mass, where the gravitational field is zero (as you can quickly show with Gauss's Law for gravity). The bob simply sits at rest.

Answer (score 0):

**The period can take a wide range of values.**

If there is no mass "under" the pendulum, there is no gravitational force acting on it. In this case, the centripetal force acting on the bob will be determined entirely by the speed with which the pendulum is moving, which will determine the tension in the string. This is basically equivalent to swinging a tennis ball on a string over you head in a zero-G environment. You could pull the string lightly, imparting low centripetal acceleration and yield a long period, or pull the string very hard to impart a larger acceleration and a shorter period. If you don't give the pendulum a push to start, it'll never move at all, and if you do push it, the the period will be determined entirely by the initial velocity of the bob.

If there is mass under pendulum, the period can still take a wide range of values. You could effectively put the pendulum bob in orbit around the planetary core, and have the pendulum bob trace a circle without needing any string at all - the centripetal acceleration in this case is provided entirely by gravity, and will yield a period of about 85 minutes (see @Philip's answer). If the pendulum moved slower than that, it would fall into the core and stop oscillating. You can, however, make the pendulum circle the core even faster by imparting a larger initial velocity, in which case the centripetal acceleration is provided by the combination of gravity and tension in the string (this is basically how a space elevator works).

The period of the pendulum is upper-bounded by the amount of mass underneath the pendulum, and lower-bounded by tensile strength of the string. If the string is infinitely strong, you can make the pendulum orbit the core *as fast as you want*, equivalent to whipping a tennis ball on a string around your head as fast as possible.

The key difference from a typical pendulum is the fact that a typical pendulum always starts with an intial velocity of zero. In this case, if the pendulum starts with zero velocity, it will either fall into the core (if there is mass below), or not move at all (if there is no mass below) - you *must* select an initial velocity for the bob, which will be the only thing that determines the period of the pendulum. Since the initial velocity can take a wide range of values, so too can the period.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand parts of your answer: the argument that I have a problem with is your point that if the pendulum reaches the core it will stop oscillating. Is this because you're modelling a "real" core, or do you think this would be true for even the toy model that I describe? I feel that if you're using the toy model the bob will certainly not stop at the core, even if the force is zero there, for precisely the same reason that a mass on a spring when giving an initial displacement will not stop at its equilibrium position but oscillate around it:its inertia would carry it forward.

Comment: Secondly, I'm not sure if the statement "*a typical pendulum always starts with an initial velocity of zero*" is particularly useful: the initial conditions don't really specify the system, just the class of solutions to it. As I see it you can either place the pendulum at the centre of the sphere and have it stay still (equilibrium position) or displace it from this position and have it oscillate. I do not see an initial velocity being a requirement for oscillations at all!

Comment: Thirdly, I am confused by the idea that you could make the pendulum orbit as fast as you want. The statement: "*You can, however, make the pendulum circle the core even faster by imparting a larger initial velocity*" seems odd: imparting an initial velocity in a harmonic system would only change the trajectory, but it would not change the time period. Giving it a greater velocity would make it go further, and come back faster, in the same time. Of course, if you spun the pendulum continuously you could make it go faster, but then you could do that to any object anywhere, couldn't you?

Comment: @Philip I suppose you could have a pendulum bob with an elliptical orbit around the core which could have a different period, but I'm not sure that's well-described as a pendulum, since it would have varying length. You're right that a pendulum doesn't have to have zero velocity at the start, but the initial velocity is irrelevant to the period (within the small angle approximation). Here, the period is very much determined by the initial velocity. To clarify, does this model have a solid core and gravity, or is it just a zero-G empty "hole" at the center of the planet?

Comment: @Philip Maybe I've misunderstood the system, I'm envisioning a pendulum doing circular orbits around a central pivot. There's no swinging back and forth like in a uniform gravitational field that just points "down". By doing this around the center of the planet, you either have no gravitational field, or a non-uniform one that changes direction as you move around the core. I don't quite follow what you mean about "go further and come back faster" - the bob is just doing orbits around the center at a distance determined by the string length, and the period is determined by the bob's velocity.

Comment: @Philip Basically, the way I'm thinking of it, it's not really a pendulum at all, it's an object in orbit around a central point, where the centripetal force comes either from gravity, tension, or both. The gravitational field is non-existent or non-uniform, so there's no swinging back and forth - it's just circular motion.

Comment: Hm, my model is just a pivot point (say) at the centre of the earth, and a mass within this solid sphere that can cut out a channel for itself, for example. I feel there would be some sort of back and forth motion precisely because within a solid sphere the force is proportional to $r$ and thus non-uniform. If you released it from rest, it would oscillate in a straight line. If you impart an initial velocity, it would oscillate in 3D harmonic motion. In both cases the time period is independent of initial conditions. Perhaps you could show how the period depends on velocity?

Comment: @Philip Ah, I understand now. I had been thinking of a pendulum with a string that traces an arc as it moves around the center, not a stringless bob that moves back and forth in a line through the center. If gravity is the only force on the bob, then I believe you're correct that initial velocity won't matter. If there's a string, initial tangential velocity could result in tension in the string, causing additional centripetal acceleration, and a change in period.